# Python: How make a zip with file, not into folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

Folder contain my files and I want to make a zip with those files, and save zip into a folder.

Here my files

```
- file:
   - file_0.txt
   - file_1.txt
   - file_2.txt
- zip:
  // save zip
script.py
```

Here my code

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

zip_name = "Zipfile"
zipObj = ZipFile("zip/{}.zip".format(zip_name), "w")
count = 0
while count < 3:
    file_name = "file_"
    zipObj.write('file/' + file_name + str(count) + ".txt")
    count += 1
```

This make a Zip file with a folder named file, and inside all `txt`, I want to remove folder and only zip the files

Comment: Set ``arcname`` in [zipfile.write](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
zip_name = "Zipfile"
zipObj = ZipFile("zip/{}.zip".format(zip_name), "w")
count = 0
import os
os.chdir('file')
while count < 3:
    file_name = "file_"
    zipObj.write(file_name + str(count) + ".txt")
    count += 1
```

This should work for you